# Add "Create Tag Synonyms" to the creation tab in privileges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was going through the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) page and noticed that [Create Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) is not a member of the [creation page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=creation).  Is there a reason that it would not be consider a creation privilege?  Would we be able to add it to the creation page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already located on the [moderation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation).  So it would be redundant to put it in the creation tab.  If I had to guess, it's on the moderation tab because no *new* tags were actually made.  Behaviors were edited instead.